# cant get the message from GCM

Tags: php, android

i am building app which based on the GCM. for now i succeed to get the notification but the message that i get is a null object and i don't understand why it's happens.

this is the server side of the GCM:

```
  <?php


class GCM {



     function __construct() {

        }

        public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
            // include config
            include_once 'connection.php';

            // Set POST variables
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
                'data'             => array("message" => $message),
            );

            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' .GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and this is GCM client side implementetion:
GcmBroadcastReciever:

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.GoogleCloudNotifications;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

GCMIntentService:

```
       package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.GoogleCloudNotifications;


    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

        private static final String TAG = "GCM Tutorial::Service";

        // Use your PROJECT ID from Google API into SENDER_ID
        public static final String SENDER_ID = "8462XXXXXX";

        public GCMIntentService() {
            super(SENDER_ID);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onRegistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onUnregistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
            String message;
            // Message from PHP server
            message = data.getStringExtra("message");
            // Open a new activity called GCMMessageView
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMMessageView.class);
            // Pass data to the new activity
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            // Starts the activity on notification click
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Create the notification with a notification builder
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gpsport_logo_icon)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("GPSport Notification")
                    .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .getNotification();
            // Remove the notification on click
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);

            {
                // Wake Android Device when notification received
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                final PowerManager.WakeLock mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(
                        PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "GCM_PUSH");
                mWakelock.acquire();

                // Timer before putting Android Device to sleep mode.
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        mWakelock.release();
                    }
                };
                timer.schedule(task, 5000);
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onError: errorId=" + errorId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM returns data in bundle, Try using an array instead of using the message value directly

```
 $data=array();
  $data['message']=$message;
  $data['new_data']=$newData;
```

And then later add pass that array to the GCMfield array

```
$fields = array(
          'registration_ids' => $gcmids,
          'data' => $data,
      );
```

Also make sure that when you call send_notification function you pass !null message :)

Comment: what is the var "$newData"? i dont understand why i need it.

Comment: I meant that you can also add new data in future this way

Comment: OK i try what you suggest and its solve the problem so thank you very much. in addition i just took the following code: $data=array();
  $data['message']=$message; and chnage "$fields" as you said.

Comment: Perfect :) Your code can also work but where you used "message" => $message you should use 'message'

Comment: But using an array is recommended because it gives you future availability to add more data

Comment: Zohair, i am stil using an array.